# how to read bulk data using jtable?

Tags: jtable

I have to read 2000 records at once and have to populate into the jtable but it's taking around 12-16 seconds, i am using the ajax call and getting json data using spring controller using @ResponseBody. Please suggest the better way to get the data in around 5-6 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are fetching bulk record from the db, rather than going with Spring MVC means don't return it by using @ResponseBody, use Restful service which will return the JSON data as the part of response stream, then definitely the response time will be decreased.

Comment: ok, but i believe in the Spring and Restful we do have the servlet as an infrastructure for receiving the request and returning the response and as i am returning the json in response using @ResponseBody, So will rest will reduce the response time?

Comment: anyways thanks @BHG... i tried doing spring and restful, it worked for me.